# WebLogic 8.1 and 4096-bit SSL?

Tags: active-directory, ssl, ssl-certificate, weblogic, cryptography

We have a scenario in which we'd like to configure a WebLogic 8.1 server (running on Windows, JRockit 1.4.2) to connect to Active Directory over SSL for authentication.  Our Active Directory is configured for SSL with a Root CA and Subordinate CA that have 4096-bit keys.  We found this was unsupported in that version of the JRE, so we tried configuring BouncyCastle as the security provider, as it supports that keylength.  We've been able to configure an SSL certificate from the same CA hierarchy, and it's able to load that (we can connect via SSL with no problem).  However, when we enable SSL for Active Directory, we get an error.

Has anyone else tried running WebLogic with this configuration, or using BouncyCastle to support large keysizes, in general?

Comment: One has to ask, 4096? Even combining all the known computing power in the world it would be the Heat-death of the universe before you got through 0.0001 of the available prime-number factorizations.

Comment: For a CA with validity of 20 years, in a high-security industry?  Yes.  4096.